# How can I change the size of the square of the camera which I see things through?

Tags: camera

I have changed the size of the the rectangular box of the camera - the box you can select on the 3D view - some time ago and I can't turn it back to the old size. Can you look at the pictures and help me, please?
Thank you so much!

[image: text]

[image: text]

Comment: That is controlled by render resolution in the render panel

Answer (score 2):

The render resolution in the render panel defines the upper limits in the dimensions of all renders through the camera, final or viewport.

You can also set a Render Border, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> in Object Mode, to restrict the rendered area in all views, (further restricted by the render resolution, when looking through the camera). In the 3D view, it's delineated with a red dashed frame.

In Object Mode, hitting  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> again allows you to resize the border, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> dismisses it.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Robin! But literally sleeping on it, I woke up and ran up to my computer. Try this:

Comment: Thank you a lot, Robin! But literally sleeping on it, I woke up and ran up to my computer. Try this:
- Open a new file;
- Press Zero to go into Rendering Mode;
- Select the rectangular box so it will go Yellow;
- Zoom in;
- Grab (G) the box and play around with it;
- Press Zero and leave Rendering Mode;
- Press Zero again to go back to Rendering Mode.
- Notice that the Rectangular Box will come back always Big. If you happen to save your project with that Box big, it will always be big in that project. I do not know if that will  upset the quality or the resolution of your rendering.

Comment: Numpad 0 doesn't take you into rendering mode .. it takes you into the camera view. When you select the box and it goes yellow, you are selecting the camera you are looking through. Playing with the box is moving/rotating/scaling the camera. Change  the size of _that_ (white or yellow) box in Properties> Render tab > Dimension. You _also_ have a Render Border set in your reference picture ( the red dashed line). Use Ctrl-Alt-B in Object mode to lose that.